# c# go through an entire website

Tags: c#, selenium, traversal

Given an website URL.
Is there a way to traverse through all the links on the website and keep track of all the Pages in a text file or something. I want to use Selenium for this. 
However, some of them are pop up dialogs that will be on every header and footer of every page. So obviously keep track of visited links and not go back to them again.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes it's possible. Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: This is question about very high level task, and questions like that are not really appreciated, because they show that you did minimal effort before asking.

Comment: This is called web scraping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Scrapy: http://scrapy.org/

> Scrapy is a fast high-level screen scraping and web crawling framework, used to crawl websites and extract structured data from their pages. It can be used for a wide range of purposes, from data mining to monitoring and automated testing.